# Trying to compare values from a list in python

Tags: python

I am trying to compare values from a list.

Here is the code but it is strange that it does not work.

```
list_a = []

print("enter 2 numbers")

list_a.append(input())
list_a.append(input())

if(lista_a[x] < list_a[x+1]):
     do something....
```

If the numbers typed are 2 and 10, it won't work in spite of 2 being less than 10.

Comment: `2 < 10` but you're doing `'2' < '10'`, strings not integers folks (in Python 3). do `list_a.append(int(input()))`

Comment: And it works if i typ in 1 and 10.. but not 2 and 10

Comment: @EdChum, I'm not sure that's the right duplicate, the key point here is that `input()` `return`s a string in Python 3

Comment: Oh my lord, thanks :)

Comment: @Chris_Rands sure I overlooked the primary error, there is dupe for that too but I can't vote to dupe hammer it now so reopened

Answer (score 1):

Convert string values inside the list into int values as follows:

```
list_a = []

print("enter 2 numbers")

list_a.append(input())
list_a.append(input())

if(int(lista_a[x]) < int(list_a[x+1])):
     do something....
```